# Why is CookieSlidingExpiration set to false by default

Tags: .net, authentication, session-cookies, identityserver4

In identityServer4, I noticed that the boolean option `CookieSlidingExpiration` is set to false by default.

Does that mean that after the `DefaultCookieTimeSpan`, the user will be prompted to login again? Even if he was actively using the system the whole time?

Or am I thinking it the wrong way?

Ideally, if the user is actively using our system, they should never be prompted to enter credentials again. That would be acceptable given some time of inactivity.

Comment: Edit: ugh, misread your question.  Sorry for the bother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly. The user will get a cookie when he logs in. Then he can use the site for a time period, after that he will be logged out. See details about [SlidingExpiration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.slidingexpiration(v=vs.113).aspx) .